# Why am I getting an error for JavaScript atob when it is working on btoa?

Tags: javascript, base64

I am working on a Straight up transcriptor for practice and fun, But It works by having two sets of object: Input, Label, And a paragraph for the output, The one translating binary to ascii is working just fine, But the other way around keeps giving me errors.

Here is the whole code I threw together:

```js
//Adding comments for clarity.

//First we need to get the elements we will use for input.
const Bin = document.getElementById("binary");
const Ascii = document.getElementById("ascii");

//I will update their value, My first attempt to rectify the errors.
Bin.value = "Binary here."
Ascii.value = "Ascii here."

//These are the paragraphs that I made for the output,
//In the original, I just used the opposite input,
//But... I forgot how to work the proper event...
const BinOut = document.getElementById("Binary Output");
const AsciiOut = document.getElementById("Ascii Output");

//Dedicated function to do the work upon receiving events...
function Transcript(changingBin = false) {
  //If changingBin is true, We are reading from Ascii, Otherwise from Binary.
  let valueRead = changingBin ? Bin : Ascii;
  //Choosing the output paragraph right under it...
  let toChange = !changingBin ? BinOut : AsciiOut;
  //If we are reading from Ascii, We should use atob, Otherwise, Btoa
  let output = changingBin ? btoa(valueRead.value) : atob(valueRead.value)

  //Change the corresponding paragraph tag to include outputted results.
  return toChange.innerText = output;
}

//Makeshift event...
document.addEventListener("Tick", () => {
  Transcript(false)
})
document.addEventListener("Tick2", () => {
  Transcript(true)
})

setInterval(() => {
  //Dispatch the events to the inputs...
  let e = new CustomEvent("Tick", {});
  document.dispatchEvent(e)
  //There are two because I thought it might off somehow overwritten,
  //Not convinced, But better safe then sorry.
  let e2 = new CustomEvent("Tick2", {});
  document.dispatchEvent(e2)
  //Lovely side effect where they update as you type.
}, 60)
```

```html
<h1>Transcriptor: Ascii &lt;=&gt; Binary</h1>
<div>
  <label for="binary">Binary =&gt;</label>
  <input type="text" name="binary" id="binary" placeholder="Binary input here">
  <br>
  <p id="Ascii Output"></p>

  <br>

  <label for="ascii">Ascii =&gt;</label>
  <input type="text" name="ascii" id="ascii" placeholder="Ascii input here">
  <br>
  <p id="Binary Output"></p>
</div>
```

Here is the error I get, Directly copied and pasted:
`transcript.html:64  Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded. at Transcript (http://127.0.0.1:5500/transcript.html:64:60) at HTMLDocument.\<anonymous\> (http://127.0.0.1:5500/transcript.html:69:48) at http://127.0.0.1:5500/transcript.html:74:22`
But I am not using it for the Dom at all beyond a value of am input...
the frustrating thing is that I've done this before, But the phone it's on is iffy, If I get it back, I'll try to update this with the other code and the solved version of this if I get it...

I tried making the output separate from the inputs, This worked to get the events functioning without overwriting what I was actively typing.
I tried making the events seperate in hopes of getting it to work both ways, It did not...
I tried mapping both to the btoa in expectation that it might give me insight, But it didn't,
I mapped them both to atob hoping they would work, But then neither did.
Even when I gvot them both working, The atob won't accept pasted text nor the originally placed text as seen in the script tag on lines 61 and 62...
I tried looking it up, But all that came up was a question that asked how to set the html to reload once the user returned, To resume their session and the like.
To elaborate my intentions, I wish to encode the strings so that the caan be directly returned into btoa without need for further decryption.

Comment: [_"The atob() function decodes a string of data which has been encoded using Base64 encoding."_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/atob). Your string `"Ascii here."` is not base64 encoded

Comment: I think your logic might be back-to-front as well. The comments don't match the code

Comment: a) use try/catch to handle errors when the base64 is incomplete. b) use `input` event on the inputs to trigger changes on input, rather than blindly running 16 times a second, c) your translate function makes the code far less readable than it should be